# How do I edit my Area51 proposal?

Tags: support, edits, area-51, site-proposal

After some discussions in my proposal I'd like to generalize its target audience a bit from what it is currently. How do I go about doing that- I can't seem to find a link anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see an edit link underneath the proposal name / audience if you're the owner.

Answer (score 3):

There is some disagreement over whether proposals should be allowed to change after people have followed them.

I personally think it's OK, and necessary -- as long as the proposal doesn't go from "I love dogs!" to "I love cats!" -- but not everyone agrees.

Comment: I'd agree with you; after all, that's the point of the discussion, to gain further clarity about what kind of a site the proposal, well, proposes. Some of the time this should include alterations to the proposal itself. Perhaps if followers were notified with a banner that "'I love cats!' proposal has now changed to 'I love dogs!'" so they have a chance to unfollow?

Comment: To a lesser degree, one could alter questions after they've received up- or down-votes, yet this is currently permissible.

Comment: A banner wouldn't really be necessary: social pressure from the community should be enough to ensure the proposal doesn't change drastically.  But hey, if it does and no one complains, perhaps it was a true improvement? @fbr