# Should you be able to edit Area 51 proposals?

Tags: discussion, area-51

After reading ["How do I edit my Area51 proposal?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52052/how-do-i-edit-my-area51-proposal) I was wondering if we should be able to edit a proposal at all?

Possible reasons to edit a proposal:

- Add Clarification
- Increase Scope (for example from Cats to Pets)
- Decrease Scope (for example from Pets to Cats)
- Change in audience

Possible reasons **NOT** to edit a proposal:

- Questions have already been asked
- Users that previously followed the proposal may no longer be interested
- Users are not notified of changes to the proposal
- Votes on questions may no longer be accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do** edit a proposal to:

- correct spelling
- clarify something unclear
- correct mistakes in the proposal (e.g. using a description in the audience field)

After people start proposing questions and voting on them, **Don't** edit a proposal to:

- change the purpose of the site
- change the audience
- widen the scope (instead, be more liberal with your on-topic votes)
- narrow the scope (instead, be more liberal with your off-topic votes)

**Never** edit a proposal

- because you've lost interest
- because you think that the proposal is a terrible idea
- because you think that the proposal is too narrow
- because you think that the proposal is too wide

*Instead*, start a *new* proposal that is more on-topic.

For example, if you've proposed a site about the Boeing 737 series of jet airliners, and you realize that a site about commercial airliners in general is a much better idea, just abandon your old proposal (unfollow it) and make a new one. If the new one is really a better idea, it will attract far more followers and committers, and ultimately that's the one that's likely to get created.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the clarification I was looking for.

Comment: if we're not supposed to use the audience field for desciption, [what *are* we supposed to use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94673/area-51-how-can-we-explain-our-intended-scope-with-new-examples)?